# Weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1 upgrade

Tags: weblogic12c

I am trying to upgrade Weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1 with EJB from 2.x to 3.2. Still getting below error. Any help is appreciated.

```
**Weblogic error:**
    [java] ................WLST-WLS-1603719853107: weblogic.application.AnnotationProcessingException: weblogic.application.metadatacache.MetadataCacheException: weblogic.application.AnnotationProcessingException: weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107: There are 1 nested errors:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:535)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:86)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getClassInfoFromSource(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:360)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.access$100(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:50)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$1.call(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:342)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$1.call(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:334)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.ParallelTaskManager$ParallelTask.run(ParallelTaskManager.java:247)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoFinderFactory.newInstance(ClassInfoFinderFactory.java:195)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.initializeClassInfosIfNecessary(War.java:477)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.getHandlesImpls(War.java:437)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.DeployHelper.isJaxRsApplication(DeployHelper.java:63)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.DeployHelper.isJaxRsApplication(DeployHelper.java:50)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsModuleExtensionFactory.create(JaxRsModuleExtensionFactory.java:49)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107: Caused by: weblogic.application.metadatacache.MetadataCacheException: weblogic.application.AnnotationProcessingException: weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107:
         [java] WLST-WLS-1603719853107: There are 1 nested errors:
```

Comment: The migration tool is running out of memory. Update the migration tool script to increase the java heap size

Comment: I get below error even after increasing.  [java] Unexpected error: main.WLSTException
     [java] Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
     [java]   File "C:\....\target\app7001.localhost.py", line 427, in ?
     [java]   File "<iostream>", line 1359, in shutdown
     [java]   File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
     [java] WLSTException: Error occurred while performing shutdown : No server, cluster, system component or system component configuration with name "admin7001" configured in the domain
     [java]

Comment: How do you run the upgrade ? The errors says that there is no server named admin7001 in your domain. Can you confirm ?